# Using a youtube video? Legal or illegal?

Tags: youtube

I could not find the answer anywhere on the net, and I'm not sure if stack overflow is the right place for my question. (If not, I do apologize)

Here goes: is it illegal to post youtube videos on my website? I mean embedding it, so that other people can have direct access to the video on youtube, but of course from my website?

EDIT: I disagree with anyone stating that this isn't a coding question. Clearly, I will be programming something which will link up another website. So, despite the legal nature of the question, this question by NO means warrants -2 on the votes, as the legal nature is part of programming. For example, if you rip off something which clearly states that you need to pay a certain amount of money (fonts for example), then as a programmer you still need to pay for the font for fear of being sued. So, if I didn't know the answer to a legal question pertaining to coding, because the PROCESS involves coding, then the way to know is to ask people who deal with day to day situations similar to mine.

Comment: If it was illegal, YouTube wouldn't have a button that tells you exactly how to do it.

Comment: There's a pretty clear [TOS document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) on their website that should answer all your questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about YouTube video sharing policies.

Answer (score 2):

No its not illegal to share the YouTube videos. But there some restriction on sharing unlisted videos. Refer this link https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en

Comment: Fair point, although it doesn't tell you whether you could or not.